# Oozie Spark Action java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cloudera, oozie

I'm starting my Spark app (version: 1.6.0) on CDH 5.7.4 with Kerberos using Oozie Spark Action and in yarn-cluster mode. I'm still getting an error:

```
Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/Logging
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.Logging
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 13 more
```

What I cannot understand is that the same application started on front end node is working well. Moreover, I don't use the Logging class in my app.

Is it possible, that the spark shared lib in hdfs /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_/spark has a different state than the nominal SPARK_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.4-1.cdh5.7.4.p0.2/lib/spark?

Here my workflow.xml file:

```
<workflow-app name="myApp workflow" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
<global>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>oozie.launcher.yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env</name>
                <value>SPARK_HOME=/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.4-1.cdh5.7.4.p0.2/lib/spark</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
</global>
  <credentials>
    <credential name="hcat" type="hcat">
      <property>
        <name>hcat.metastore.uri</name>
        <value>thrift://<XXX></value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>hcat.metastore.principal</name>
        <value>hive/<XXX></value>
      </property>
    </credential>
  </credentials>
    <start to="spark"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="spark" cred="hcat">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <master>yarn</master>
            <mode>cluster</mode>
            <name>AppName</name>
              <class>main.Class</class>
            <jar>${nameNode}/<path>/myJar.jar</jar>
              <spark-opts> --files ${nameNode}/<path>/hive-site.xml, ${nameNode}/<path>/file.conf</spark-opts>
              <arg>--mode history</arg>
              <arg>--base-timestamp 2016-01-20#00:00:00</arg>
              <arg>--conf file.conf</arg>
        </spark>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Any thoughts on what I am missing?

Comment: In CDH 5.9 (and that should also be true for CDH 5.7)  the "local" Spark install on Edge Node uses an uber-JAR (`ls -l /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/lib/spark-assembly-*.jar`), while the Oozie sharelib contains the individual JARs. The `Logging` class should be present in `spark-core-*.jar` so if you are missing *that* JAR in the sharelib, yes, you are in trouble...!

Comment: BTW the HDFS path that you mention for the Oozie sharelib (`/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_/spark/`) is **pretty smelly**, because the "lib_" should be followed by a timestamp... Check that Oozie is picking the correct sharelib directory cf. https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Getting_list_of_available_sharelib

Comment: Also, check the YARN log for your Spark action exec in Oozie, it should contain a very verbose list of all JARs that Oozie has downloaded from the sharelib. If that list contains `spark-core-*.jar` then you hit a bizarre Scala CLASSPATH bug (good luck to solve it); otherwise it's an Oozie sharelib issue.